# How can I get number of followers with Spotify API?

Tags: php, spotify, spotify-app

I'm trying to get an artist's number of followers.

If I use the metadata api call

```
http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:artist:4YrKBkKSVeqDamzBPWVnSJ
```

I just get the name of the artist.

Comment: use spotify api-> https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-artist/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a PHP solution.

Using the [spotify-web-api-php](https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php) library (shameless self promotion) it's really easy. Take a look at this example:

```
<?php
require_once 'src/Request.php';
require_once 'src/SpotifyWebAPI.php';

$api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();
$artist = $api->getArtist('0OdUWJ0sBjDrqHygGUXeCF');

echo '<b>Number of followers:</b> ' . $artist->followers->total;
```

As mentioned earlier, also take a look at the [official Spotify docs](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-artist/).

Comment: Yes that's it ! I wonder if I can get access token without asking user to login (cf. https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow), without using redirect uri, just using client_id and client_secret.

Comment: Take a look at the [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) and the method for it in [my library](http://jwilsson.github.io/spotify-web-api-php/authorization.html#client-credentials-flow). A value for the redirect uri is currently needed but it can just be an empty string.